# How to solve the 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException' error in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, methods, laravel-5

I have got an error

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException

when I am using 'post' in my route:

```
Route::post('SeeDetail', [
        'uses' => 'DataController@SeeDetail',
        'as' => 'SeeDetail'
        ]);
```

But, if I am using 'get' in my route, there's no error but I have a `data_id` in the link (localhost/survey/public/SeeDetail?data_id=1). 
Do you know how to make the `data_id` disappear from the link (localhost/survey/public/SeeDetail)?
Button in my view like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('SeeDetail', ['data_id'=>$getData->data_id])}}" class="btn btn-default">
```

Comment: Anchor tags make `GET` requests, not `POST` requests.

Comment: You have created POST route but tried to call that route with GET HTTP method. 
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send a `get` request not `post` request. You need to use `get` instead of `post`. But you also pass parameter in the URL but you don't specify in your route.

Try this:

```
Route::get('SeeDetail/{data_id}', [
    'uses' => 'DataController@SeeDetail',
    'as' => 'SeeDetail'
]);
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#required-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

In route, You have mensioned it as a post method. But you accessing as get method. If you want "post" method, try to use form, else mension the route as get instead of post.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned links use `GET` method, and thus if you define your route as `POST` Laravel cannot match it and throws `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

To pass some additional data in the request you can use `POST` method and form with hidden field.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('SeeDetail') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="data_id" value="{{ $getData->data_id }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
</form>
```

However keep in mind that `POST` request should be used for data manipulation, after which browser is redirected to `GET` page. This way you will achieve fluid navigation without any "Confirm re-sending" dialogs and problems when user refreshes the page.